# Formatear XML en tabla dinámica con XSL no funciona

Tags: xml, xsl

Resulta que tengo un xml dinámico que es la respuesta de un http request, al aplicarle una hoja de estilo XSL, no funciona, pero descubrí que cambiando:

```
xmlns="http://www.yahoo.com/schemas/messages"
```

por:

```
xmlnsi="http://www.yahoo.com/schemas/messages"
```

el script funciona, pero no encuentro explicación alguna, podrían ayudarme a encontrar una solución sin tener que hacer el cambio al xmlns. Gracias de antemano.

Este es mi XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<availabilityRS
    xmlnsi="http://www.yahoo.com/schemas/messages"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" schemaLocation="http://www.yahoo.com/schemas/messages">
    <auditData processTime="134" timestamp="2017-05-22 20:15:33.233" requestHost="65.44.252.333" serverId="sa37AUX3R23332.env" environment="[int]" release="09748902233322333222337b" token="332233233-2233-2233-3322-2233322233b1" internal="0|2233223322332233233444433433|MX|01|8|42|5,5|||||||||||83||1~2~2~2||0||0|2emmxkmta34a7gan9f4xdqq7||"/>
    <hotels checkIn="2017-05-24" total="8" checkOut="2017-05-25">
        <hotel code="20078" name="Las Brisas Acapulco" categoryCode="5EST" categoryName="5 STARS" destinationCode="ACA" destinationName="Acapulco" zoneCode="20" zoneName="Bahia" latitude="16.8263934714721" longitude="-99.8623721580134" minRate="4059.90" maxRate="4772.52" currency="MXN">
            <rooms>
                <room code="DBL.ST-1" name="DOUBLE STANDARD">
                    <rates>
                        <rate rateKey="20170524|20170525|W|71|20078|DBL.ST-1|CGW-MEXB2BMXN|RO||2~2~2|4~8|N@952F0BCE487A4AC3AC73918BCE4C7814" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="4059.90" allotment="9" rateCommentsId="71|33975|0" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="RO" boardName="ROOM ONLY" rooms="2" adults="2" children="2" childrenAges="4,8">
                            <cancellationPolicies>
                                <cancellationPolicy amount="4059.90" from="2017-05-21T23:59:00-05:00"/>
                            </cancellationPolicies>
                            <promotions>
                                <promotion code="044" name="15% Special Discount applied" remark="*** special discount rates ***"/>
                            </promotions>
                            <offers>
                                <offer code="9002" name="Early Booking discount" amount="-716.46"/>
                                <offer code="9001" name="Child discount" amount="-4776.36"/>
                            </offers>
                        </rate>
                    </rates>
                </room>
                <room code="DBL.PP" name="DOUBLE WITH PRIVATE POOL">
                    <rates>
                        <rate rateKey="20170524|20170525|W|71|20078|DBL.PP|CGW-MEXB2BMXN|RO||2~2~2|4~8|N@952F0BCE487A4AC3AC73918BCE4C7814" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="4772.52" allotment="9" rateCommentsId="71|33975|0" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="RO" boardName="ROOM ONLY" rooms="2" adults="2" children="2" childrenAges="4,8">
                            <cancellationPolicies>
                                <cancellationPolicy amount="4772.52" from="2017-05-21T23:59:00-05:00"/>
                            </cancellationPolicies>
                            <promotions>
                                <promotion code="044" name="15% Special Discount applied" remark="*** special discount rates ***"/>
                            </promotions>
                            <offers>
                                <offer code="9002" name="Early Booking discount" amount="-842.22"/>
                                <offer code="9001" name="Child discount" amount="-5614.76"/>
                            </offers>
                        </rate>
                    </rates>
                </room>
            </rooms>
        </hotel>
    </hotels>
</availabilityRS>
```

Y este es mi XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="*">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Búsqueda en Acapulco</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="color:blue;text-align:center">Hotel</th>
        <th style="color:blue;text-align:center">Destino</th>
<th style="color:blue;text-align:center">Categoría</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="hotels/hotel">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@destinationName"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@categoryName"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con una declaración de `<availabilityRS xmlns="http://www.yahoo.com/schemas/messages">...</availabilityRS>` los elementos de este documento pertenecen al "namespace" (espacio de nombres) `http://www.yahoo.com/schemas/messages` y con XSLT y XPath, para seleccionarlos en el programa, tienes dos opciones. Si utilizas XSLT 2.0 (con Saxon 9 o XmlPrime o XmlSpy o oXygen o similar) simplemente puedes utilizar `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.yahoo.com/schemas/messages"`, es decir:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.yahoo.com/schemas/messages">
<xsl:template match="*">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Búsqueda en Acapulco</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="color:blue;text-align:center">Hotel</th>
        <th style="color:blue;text-align:center">Destino</th>
<th style="color:blue;text-align:center">Categoría</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="hotels/hotel">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@destinationName"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@categoryName"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Acabo de poner un ejemplo: http://xsltransform.net/3MvmrzF.

Si solos tienes acceso a XSLT 1.0, en tu programa de XSLT tienes que definir un prefijo para el "namespace" y utilizarlo en las expresiones de XPath, como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:yh="http://www.yahoo.com/schemas/messages" exclude-result-prefixes="yh">
<xsl:template match="*">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Búsqueda en Acapulco</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="color:blue;text-align:center">Hotel</th>
        <th style="color:blue;text-align:center">Destino</th>
<th style="color:blue;text-align:center">Categoría</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="yh:hotels/yh:hotel">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@destinationName"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@categoryName"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

En línea: http://xsltransform.net/6pS1zCH

Comment: Funciona a la perfección, muchas gracias, resolución sencilla y eficiente.